# WordPress 6.0 - Theme.json Color Palette doesn't apply to Frontend

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Hello Stackoverflow Users,

I'm trying to create a WordPress 6.0 Fullsite Editing Theme. But I am running into a issue which is driving me crazy.

I enabled a color palette in my theme.json file and can select the colors within the gutenberg editor. The Backend is even showing the correct colors.

[Correct Colors within Gutenberg Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1JZp.png)

The frontend doesn't show the chosen colors from the Color pallete though. The Class is applied, but the color doesn't show up in the CSS.

[No Color applied in the Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZBz.png)

If I apply a custom color from the color pallette, everything is working fine though.

[Custom Colors are working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhiaN.png)

[Custom Colors are working in the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJmOR.png)

So I suspect, something in my theme.json is wrong.
Does someone has an Idea, what could cause this issue?

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "color": {
            "defaultPalette": false,
            "defaultGradients": false,
            "link": true,
            "custom": true,
            "background": true,
            "duotone": [
            ],
            "palette": [
                {
                    "slug": "white",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "name": "Weiß"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "primary",
                    "color": "#D4B86A",
                    "name": "Akzentfarbe"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "black",
                    "color": "#000",
                    "name": "Schwarz"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "lightgrey",
                    "color": "#ECECEC",
                    "name": "Helles Grau"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "grey",
                    "color": "#D9D9D9",
                    "name": "Grau"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "darkgrey",
                    "color": "#3E3E3E",
                    "name": "Dunkles Grau"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "transparent",
                    "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
                    "name": "Transparent"
                }
            ],
            "gradients": [
                {
                    "slug": "",
                    "gradient": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "spacing": {
            "units": [
                "%",
                "px",
                "em",
                "rem",
                "vh",
                "vw"
            ]
        },
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "800px",
            "wideSize": "1425px"
        },
        "typography": {
            "dropCap": false,
            "fontFamilies": [
                {
                    "fontFamily": "Jost",
                    "name": "Jost",
                    "slug": "jost",
                    "fontFace": [
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Jost",
                            "fontWeight": "300 400 700",
                            "fontStyle": "normal",
                            "src": [ "file:./assets/fonts/../fonts/jost-v13-latin-regular.woff2" ]
                        },
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "Jost",
                            "fontWeight": "300 400 700",
                            "fontStyle": "italic",
                            "src": [ "file:./assets/fonts/jost-v13-latin-300italic.woff2" ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                    "name": "Brandon-grotesque",
                    "slug": "brandon-grotesque",
                    "fontFace": [
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                            "fontWeight": "400 700",
                            "fontStyle": "normal",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "src": [ "https://use.typekit.net/af/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                        {
                            "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                            "fontWeight": "400 700",
                            "fontStyle": "italic",
                            "fontStretch": "normal",
                            "src": [ "https://use.typekit.net/af/32d3ee/XXXXXXXXXXX" ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "fontSizes": [
                {
                    "size": "0.8rem",
                    "slug": "small",
                    "name": "Kleine Schrift"
                },
                {
                    "size": "clamp(1rem, 1rem + 2px, 1.2rem)",
                    "slug": "normal",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "size": "clamp(0.8rem, 1rem + 4px, 1.3rem)",
                    "slug": "medium",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                {
                    "size": "clamp(1.2rem, 1rem + 1vw, 1.4rem)",
                    "slug": "large",
                    "name": "Große Schrift"
            
                },
                {
                    "size": "clamp(1.2rem, 1rem + 1vw, 1.5rem)",
                    "slug": "x-large",
                    "name": "Sehr große Schrift"
                }
            ],
            "customFontSize": true
        },
        "custom": {
            "spacing": {
                "small": "",
                "medium": "",
                "large": "",
                "outer": "20px"
            },
            "typography": {
                "font-size": {
                    "huge": "clamp(2.25rem, 4vw, 2.75rem)",
                    "gigantic": "clamp(2rem, 45px, 3rem)",
                    "colossal": "clamp(3.25rem, 8vw, 6.25rem)"
                },
                "line-height": {
                    "tiny": 1.0,
                    "small": 1.1,
                    "medium": 1.3,
                    "normal": 1.4,
                    "large": 1.6
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "styles": {
        "spacing":{
            "blockGap": "1.5rem"
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--normal",
            "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
            "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--normal)"
        },
        "elements": {
            "h1": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "h2": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "h3": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "h4": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "h5": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "h6": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
                    "fontWeight": "700",
                    "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--medium)",
                    "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--gigantic)"
                }
            },
            "link": {
                "color": {
                    "text": "var(--wp--preset--color--primary)"
                }
            }
        },
        "blocks": {}
    },
    "templateParts": [
        {
            "name": "header",
            "title": "Header",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "footer",
            "title": "Footer",
            "area": "footer"
        }
    ],
    "customTemplates": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "title": "",
            "postTypes": [ "post","page" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The Issue was caused by a syntax error inside of my theme.json.

The CSS Variables generated from your theme.json will be accessible in your htmls body tag. As I was checking the outputted CSS, i noticed, that the CSS Classes are actually existing, but was loaded in the wrong css property.

[Css Variables within FontSize? Must be wrong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoQ8J.png)

So I checked all the fontSize properties, and found a missing bracket!

```
 "typography": {
            "fontSize": "var(--wp--custom--typography--font-size--normal"**)**,
            "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--jost)",
            "lineHeight": "var(--wp--custom--typography--line-height--normal)"
        },
```

... now, everything is working properly!

Answer (score 0):

You actually had a typo in this block:

```
{
                "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                "name": "Brandon-grotesque",
                "slug": "brandon-grotesque",
                "fontFace": [
                    {
                        "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                        "fontWeight": "400 700",
                        "fontStyle": "normal",
                        "fontStretch": "normal",
                        "src": [ "https://use.typekit.net/af/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                    {
                        "fontFamily": "brandon-grotesque",
                        "fontWeight": "400 700",
                        "fontStyle": "italic",
                        "fontStretch": "normal",
                        "src": [ "https://use.typekit.net/af/32d3ee/XXXXXXXXXXX" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

There's "}" instead of "]" on the "src" definition of the first normal font that you're defining.